# CSS: div with background image not displaying

Tags: css

At this site, there is a `div.social` below the Online Bookings at top right of the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlgx.jpg

Note: I've not been able to upload images to SO for months - always says the image is too large (> 2MB) when it is 140 KB.

For some reason `.social` is not displaying, nor its sub-elements:

```
<div class="social"> 

  <a title="Trip Advisor" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="tripAdvisor"></div>
  </a> 

  <a title="Facebook" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="facebook"></div>
  </a> 

  <a title="Instagram" target="_blank" href="#">
  <div class="instagram"></div>
  </a> 

  <a title="YouTube" target="_blank" href="#">
  <div class="youtube"></div>
  </a>

</div>

<style>
.headRight .tripAdvisor {
    background: url(../images/social/tripadvisor.png) no-repeat;
    width: 28px;
    height: 22px;
}
</style>
```

`.social` is set to `display: block;` and there is enough room to fit the icons in.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Please include all the relevant CSS in your question, thanks

Comment: It's a class. So you need to use `.social` and not `#social`

Comment: Oops sry, fixed (the question) {edited}.

Comment: @Steve : Did you fix the issue or just the question ?

Comment: sry, fixed the question

Comment: Are you using Adblocker? If yes, deactivate it.

Comment: no ad blocker installed. Browser is Chrome/Windows.

Comment: @Steve: I've answered it below.

Comment: @Steve: let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the bug on your website.

You must apply the style to the child divs of `.social`

```
.social div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline;   // remove this line
    zoom: 1;
}
```

remove the

```
"display: inline"
```

Just keep

```
.social div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

from that class. Will work perfectly.

Comment: Beaut. Thanks mechanicals!

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes from when the answer is made before accepting it.